# Drupal: Change database default type

Tags: sqlite, drupal-7

when i install new site by drupal i show this message :-

```
The type of database your Drupal data will be stored in. Your PHP
configuration only supports a single database type, so it has been
automatically selected.
```

I need to add database name and user and password, but i cannot see it, where can i add it.

its show me this error:-

```
In order for Drupal to work, and to continue with the installation process, you must resolve all issues reported below. For more help with configuring your database server, see the installation handbook. If you are unsure what any of this means you should probably contact your hosting provider.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the message about your system supporting just a single database type because Drupal cannot find in your system the required extensions to connect to a database. In this case Drupal assumes that you will use an Sqlite database, and it should ask you for a database file name, with no user or password. If you don't even see that option, probably your system doesn't support any database at all.

If you want to use a database server (MySql or postgres), you need at least php-pdo, php-mysql (or php-pgsql if you use postgres) installed on your system. How you install those php extensions depends on you system.